# How do I breed a Forge dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I've heard of a new hybrid dragon, the Forge dragon. How can I breed one and how will I know I have a Forge dragon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Forge Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Forge_Dragon) just requires a breed involving a **Fire Dragon and a Metal Dragon**, though you might also get a Brass Dragon instead.

Forge Dragons have a breeding time of 24 hours while Brass has a breeding time of 5 hours, so by the incubation time you'll know which dragon you'll get.

Comment: I can confirm that Fire + Metal Hybrid also works.

Answer (score 0):

Level 11 blazing right. Level 10 steel left. Got mine in the breeding cave.

Answer (score 0):

Got mine on the island with a simple lvl 10 fire on right and a lvl 10 iron on left.

Answer (score 0):

Got mine by using a few combinations

Blazing dragon with Steel dragon which gets Forge dragon

Fire dragon with Metal dragon which gets a Forge dragon

Lava dragon with any Metal type dragon which gets a Forge dragon

Brass dragon lv.11 with lv.10 Metal dragon

Metal dragon with Brass dragon